# getting error with Glide assert: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on the main thread

Tags: android, android-glide

i want to get the bitmap from url and then want to convert it into byte array for storing it into sqlite, i am using the glide for getting the bitmap from url here is my code

```
Bitmap temp = null;
    Bitmap temp2 = null;
    try {
        temp = Glide.with(this)
                .load(urlNavHeaderBg)
                .asBitmap()
                .into(-1, -1)
                .get();

        temp2 = Glide.with(this)
                .load(profile_pic_url)
                .asBitmap()
                .into(-1, -1)
                .get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

if anyone having better idea to get bitmap and convert it into byte array then feel free to suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
 Glide.with(this)
      .load(urlNavHeaderBg)
      .asBitmap()
      .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder_image)
      .error(R.drawable.place_holder_image)
      .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
          @Override
         public void onResourceReady(final Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
              Bitmap bimtapImage=resource;
             //Convert this bimtapImage to byte array 
          }
         @Override
         public void onLoadFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
             super.onLoadFailed(e, errorDrawable);
         }
  });
```

Comment: how can i get bitmap of that image from this as i want to convert it into bytearray

Comment: Bitmap resource inside onResourceReady gives you image in bitmap only

Comment: so in onResourceReady methode i create one bitmap variable and assign it Bitmap resource object?

Comment: Updated..check that

Comment: Thanks, i will test it and report back to you